# Writing in parallel to MongoDb collection from python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I would like to know how to insert into same MongoDb collection from different python scripts running at the same time using pymongo

any help redirecting guidance would be very appreciated because I couldn't find any clear documentation in pymongo or mongdb about it yet

thank in advance

Comment: by default it will work. Mongo can accept multiple incoming connections, So no problem. Go ahead write code and run it. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just insert into the collection in parallel without needing to do anything special.  If you are updating documents then you might find there are issues with locking, and depending on the storage engine which your MongoDB is using there may be collection locking, but this should not affect how you write your python script.